# Merge arrays together

Tags: php, arrays

I have these two arrays and I want to combine them into one. Using the duplicate values from 0,1 in the second array. Below is an example of how I would want it to look. I hope someone can help.

```
Array(
    [201500001] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1003123603
            [1] => 3062226597
        )

    [201500002] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3067005512
        )

)
Array(
    [1127893457] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1003123603
            [1] => 
        )

    [1127893467] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1003133106
            [1] => 3067005512
        )

    [1127893443] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1004146393
            [1] => 3062226597
        )

    [1127893246] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1003154423
            [1] => 5149282937
        )

)
```

Expected output:

```
   Array(
    [1127893457] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1003123603
            [1] => 
            [2] => 201500001
        )

    [1127893467] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1003133106
            [1] => 3067005512
            [2] => 201500002
        )

    [1127893443] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1004146393
            [1] => 3062226597
            [2] => 201500001
        )

    [1127893246] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1003154423
            [1] => 5149282937
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't understand which way you are merging to generate the expected output. Can you pls better explain it?

Comment: Has to be done this way so I can keep track of a database query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your various arrays as valid arrays. Other than that, I think that what you are looking for is to use `array_intersect`. This works for me:

```
$source = array(
    201500001 => array(
        0 => 1003123603,
        1 => 3062226597
    ),
    201500002 => array(
        0 => 3067005512
    )
);

$target = array(
    1127893457 => array(
        0 => 1003123603
    ),
    1127893467 => array(
        0 => 1003133106,
        1 => 3067005512
    ),
    1127893443 => array(
        0 => 1004146393,
        1 => 3062226597
    ),
    1127893246 => array(
        0 => 1003154423,
        1 => 5149282937
    )
);

$expected = array(
    1127893457 => array(
        0 => 1003123603,
        2 => 201500001
    ),
    1127893467 => array(
        0 => 1003133106,
        1 => 3067005512,
        2 => 201500002
    ),
    1127893443 => array(
        0 => 1004146393,
        1 => 3062226597,
        2 => 201500001
    ),
    1127893246 => array(
        0 => 1003154423,
        1 => 5149282937
    )
);

$newArray = [];

foreach ($target as $targetKey => $targetValue) {
    foreach ($source as $sourceKey => $sourceValue) {
        if (array_intersect($sourceValue, $targetValue)) {
            $targetValue[2] = $sourceKey;
        }
        $newArray[$targetKey] = $targetValue;
    }
}

echo ($newArray === $expected) ? "Match!" : "Miss." . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks solved my question!

Answer (score 0):

Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Please look at the expected output. Array_merge will not work.